# Create a descriptive statistic table in r

Tags: r

I am currently working on a replication project. I have a fairly good understanding of how to run the descriptive statistics in an R Notebook, but how do I then get the Notebook to create a table like this one below?

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far? do you have data you can share?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check `?dput()`). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!